# Multiple image elements all fading when hovered in Jquery.

Tags: jquery, hover, opacity, element, fade

I'm having an issue with applying a fade to just one element on the page with the same ID.

Firstly I fade the image down to 60% and then on hover I would like it to just 100% the image. This part works but it applies the effect to every element on the page.

```
// Fading images
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.mainArticle img').fadeTo('slow', 0.6);

$('.mainArticle img, .articleContainer').hover(function(){

    $(this).find('.mainArticle img, .articleContainer').stop(true,true).fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
},function(){
    $(this).find('.mainArticle img, .articleContainer').stop(true,true).fadeTo("slow", 0.6); 
}); 
});
```

Also I know this can be done if CSS but trying to be as compatible as possible.

Hope you guys can help,

Cheers,

Tom

Comment: Post your `html`, your `selector` is probably grabbing more than you want.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I am curious if you looked at the jsFiddles I posted.

Answer (score 3):

You are `find()`ing the same elements again. `$(this)` is the hovered element, so you can just use this for your hover handler:

```
$('.mainArticle img, .articleContainer').hover(function(){
  $(this).stop(true,true).fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
},function(){
  $(this).stop(true,true).fadeTo("slow", 0.6); 
});
```

However, I think I understand what you are trying to do, and depending on your HTML (if you could post your HTML it would be a lot easier), you'll probably want to change it to something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.mainArticle img').fadeTo('slow', 0.6);

  $('.articleContainer').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.mainArticle img').stop(true,true).fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
  },function(){
    $(this).find('.mainArticle img').stop(true,true).fadeTo("slow", 0.6); 
  });
});
```

---

With only one image to fade: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gPEQv/)

With multiple images to fade: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K587U/1/)

Comment: Great, thanks for this. Any clue as to the multiple element part?

Comment: If the `.mainArticle` elements are INSIDE an `.articleContainer`, you will get unexpected results

Comment: The `.articleContainer` can be completely removed. Also it is not within `.articleContainer`

Comment: You'll need to post your HTML. I'll put it in a jsFiddle for you

Answer (score 0):

How about just using $(this) instead of $(this).find('.mainArticle img, .articleContainer')?

You're selecting every element that matches that selector, but since you're already hovering one, you could just use $(this) and perform the change there.

Comment: Afraid that one doesn't either, however the shorthand is extremely useful. Thanks for the help.