# Jquery fade to making hidden images appear

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a fading effect to my page,  but once I add this code it makes other images I have set to display:none in css reappear.How can I get this to work on the selected divider only?

```
<div class="tiles">
```

"image code here"

```
 <script>   
            $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".tiles img").fadeTo("slow", 1.0); // This sets the opacity of the thumbs to fade when the page loads
    $(".tiles img").hover(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.6); // This should set the opacity on hover
     },function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0); // This should set the opacity back on mouseout
    });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple image elements all fading when hovered in Jquery.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402897/multiple-image-elements-all-fading-when-hovered-in-jquery)

Comment: Elaborate on 'selected divider only'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure without seeing the rest of your page code, but you might try replacing `<div class="tiles">` with `<div class="tiles" id="fade_this">` and change `$(".tiles img")` to `$("#fade_this img")`